# My first MS stereo setup.

Tags: microphone, field-recording, ms, stereo

I've been getting some great suggestions through email correspondence but I wanted to put this question out to ya'll.

You have $4000 and you want to buy a M-S stereo microphone setup(zeppelin and furry included) What would you get?

Answer (score 5):

- Sennheiser MKH 40
- Sennheiser MKH 30
- Rycote suspension w/ pistol grip
- Rycote Stereo Windshield size AE
- Rycote Stereo Windjammer Rycote
- Stereo Connbox Rycote MS stereo mic clips
- Boom pole of your choice

The only alternative I'd consider is a Schoeps MS rig, but $4k will barely cover the capsules and power supplies. But equally sweet, for different reasons. If a recorder needs to be factored in, hmm, it gets more challenging, and you start looking at single MS integrated mics...

Comment: no recorder, just what you listed above.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. But I'd suggest looking at an MKH 8040 or 8050 instead of the MKH 40. 8050 if you're mostly recording spot fx, and 8040 if you're mostly recording ambiences.

Comment: @Justin's got a great point. Sadly there's no 8030, but an 8000-series mid channel is a lot smaller and can get some crazy high frequencies. Great alternate suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use an 8050 with that setup you are going to need to spend some time learning the pickup pattern and how that affects your decoded MS. The little lobe in the back can play tricks on your image when items move from behind the ring to around the front. Just get a feel for it. Have someone ride a bicycle around the rig and you'll know what I mean.

Comment: I agree and often switch from hyper to cardiod in the center. With a hypercardiod in the mid channel, I find that decoding 1:1 frequently makes the stereo image too wide. It's often best to back off the side a little. An 8040 will give you a smoother stereo image, with more reflections in the center channel.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at this new gear. The Dovetail: passive Mid-Side encoder.

http://www.glenglenn.com

Answer (score 0):

- Rycote suspension w/ pistol grip
- Rycote Stereo Windshield size AE
- Rycote Stereo Windjammer Rycote
- Stereo Connbox Rycote MS stereo mic clips
- Boom pole of your choice
  (like NoiseJockey)

  - Neumann KM120
  - Neumann KM140/184